# How can I estimate an x variable from a y variable in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Here is my data:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
    CFU strain diltn
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 159   aM12    8748
2 124.  aM12    2916
3  76.5 aM12     972
4  22   aM12     324
5  16.5 aM12     108
6  17   aM12      36
7  22.5 aM12      12
8  17.5 aM12       4
```

This may seem like a simple question but I have mainly used R to get basic summaries of data, and graph them (using the dplyr and ggplot).

I can plot the graph:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=diltn, y=CFU))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

I would like to estimate at what "diltn" (x variable), I would get 77 "CFU" (y variable).

I managed this in excel and graphed it as follows to illustrate what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: What you are doing with the plot seems wrong. If you want to predict `diltn` from `CFU`, you should first regress `diltn` on `CFU`  (for example `lm(diltn ~ CFY, data) `) and then predict (which you can use the `predict` function).

Comment: The OP would have to clarify, but I suspect this is a dose-response curve (or something similar).  The x-axis is the independent variable, and the y-axis is the dependent variable.  It needs to be modeled that way.

Comment: It is similar to a dose response curve yes. The graphs are purely to demonstrate what I want to achieve visually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a much trickier question (in general) than it looks.  It's not that it can't be done (there are many options), but it depends greatly on how your data behaves.  For example, suppose the y-value of interest is 20 instead of 77.  Any value of diltn between 4 and 324 is now a "reasonable" answer.

To get around this issue, we use statistical models.  If I'm guessing correctly and  you're working with a dose-response model (or something similar - e.g. I've used them with standard curves in assays), you might check out `drm()` in the `drc` package, which can fit these curves appropriately.

Something like:

```
mod <- drm(CFU ~ diltn, data = data, fct = LL.4())
plot(mod)
```

[image: dose response curve]
The `ED` function is then used to extract the relevant data.  I work with standard curves, and I find the following settings to be useful, but you might need different ones depending on how your data works.

```
ED(mod, 77, bound = FALSE, type = 'absolute')
# Estimated effective doses
# 
#        Estimate Std. Error
# e:1:77  1103.69     176.31
```

It's been awhile since I read the vignettes on it though, so you will probably need to do some reading to make sure you get the correct result.

Comment: Seems like this package will do exactly what U want, just need to get down to the nitty gritty of learning to use it..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the scatter plot, we can probably fit a non-linear regression line to the dataset. Assuming your dataset is called `dat`. We can use the `nls` function to fit the regression model. Notice that it takes some efforts and thinking to find the possible equation and starting values. In this case, the equation is `CFU ~ a * diltn/(b + diltn)` and the starting value for `a` and `b` are `100` and `1000`, respectively.

```
library(tidyverse)

fit <- nls(formula = CFU ~ a * diltn/(b + diltn), 
           start = list(a = 100, b = 1000), data = dat)

summary(fit)

# Formula: CFU ~ a * diltn/(b + diltn)
# 
# Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# a   187.32      21.25   8.814 0.000118 ***
# b  1514.27     517.50   2.926 0.026420 *  
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 13.17 on 6 degrees of freedom
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 4 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.555e-06
```

To visually inspect the model fit, we can first create a second data frame with `diltn` from 1 to 9000. We can then use the `predict` function to predict the CFU based on `diltn` and the model `fit`.

```
dat2 <- data_frame(diltn = 1:9000) %>% 
  mutate(Pred = predict(fit, .))

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = diltn, y = CFU))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = dat2, aes(x = diltn, y = Pred), color = "red")
```

[image]

The model looks good to me.

Finally, we can filter the `Pred` values to find the possible values for `diltn`. In this case, I think `1057` could be a possible answer.

```
dat2 %>% filter(Pred > 76.9, Pred < 77.1)

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   diltn  Pred
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1  1055  76.9
# 2  1056  77.0
# 3  1057  77.0
# 4  1058  77.0
# 5  1059  77.1
```

Or since we have fitted a non-linear regression model and we know the fitted parameter `a` and `b`, we can set `CFU` = `77` and calculate the `diltn`. My calculation shows `diltn` is `1056.914`.